# Generically typed visitor getting called on wrong types

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, visitor-pattern

I am using a generic abstract class of a framework `AbstractProcessor<T extends CtElement>` which is basically a visitor that visits all elements T. There is a method

```
public void process(T element)
```

that acts upon all elements of the specified type and does something.

I then have concrete class implementations of this `AbstractProcessor` that I create using some sort of factory pattern, while holding a list of the common supertype `AbstractProcessor` to then call the `process`-method via polymorphism on them. One of these concrete classes might be smth like `XYZProcessor<T extends CtElement> extends AbstractProcessor<T>`.

I now create these concrete processors like `new XYZProcessor<CtNamedElement>()` where `CtNamedElement` is a subtype of `CtElement`, so the `process`-method of the `XYZProcessor` only gets called with CTNamedElements. But the `process`-method seems to get called for all visisted elements of type `CtElement`, NOT only for those of the type `CtNamedElement` as I want to.

Does anyone know what is happening here?

EDIT: relevant code:

creating processors like this

```
case CLASS:
 //CtClass is subtype of CtNamedElement
 this.setProcessor(new AnnotatedWithProcessor<CtClass>(targetName, attributeMappings, metapackage));
break;
```

Class definition:

```
public class AnnotatedWithProcessor<T extends CtNamedElement> extends AbstractProcessor<T> {
    @Override
    public void process(T element) {
     //do stuff here with elements of correct type
    }
```

And then calling the processors like this:

```
//this gets set with a concrete case like above
AbstractProcessor<?> processor;
...
//this astModel gets processed with the respective processor,
//where I expect the process method only getting called for the correct types (in this case only when coming over elements of type CtClass),
//but the method gets called for all types of CtNamedElement, not only for those of type CtClass
this.astModel.processWith(processor);
```

Comment: Please share the relevant code.

Comment: Added the relevant code in original question

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're doing so illegal casting somewhere, but it's hard to tell without seeing more of your implementation. Who is calling `XYZProcessor::process`? Why do you expect defining a generic interface to perform any sort of filtering?

Going to take a shot in the dark here, but it seems like what you probably want is a lookup map for types versus processors. This kind of code can get messy, so it's a good idea to limit access to this mapping using well tested methods:

```
private final Map<Class, Object> processorMap = new HashMap<Class, Object>();

public <T extends CtElement> void putProcessor(
    Class<T> elementClass, 
    AbstractProcessor<? extends T> processor
) {
     processorMap.put(elementClass, processor);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends CtElement> AbstractProcessor<? extends T> getProcessor(
    Class<T> elementClass,
) {
    return (AbstractProcessor<? extends T>) processorMap.get(elementClass);
}
```

Now when you search for a processor, you can use this map to find the correct implementation to call:

```
public void <T extends CtElement> process(T element) {
    getProcessor(element.getClass()).process(element);
}
```

You may want to extend this to allow multiple implementations for each class, or filter the `processorMap` for all valid processors for `element.getClass()` using `Class::isInstance` and then processing for each valid key.

Comment: What I actually want to do is having a visitor to go over a Java project's AST (this is what the framework where the AbstractProcessor is from provides) and get all elements that are annotated with a certain annotation. So the AnnotatedWithProcessor traverses the Java project and shall do smth with the code element that is annotated with a certain annotation. The type parameter shall specify whether I want to do the process-stuff with classes, methods etc. that have the annotation attached to it. I could also just check in the process-method the type of the element, but wanted smth cleaner